# HEX байткод -> very long INT

Tags: алгоритм, php, c++

Возникла необычная задача, для удобства можно считать, что она связана с шифрованием.

Допустим, есть файл, абсолютно любой (возьмем бинарный). Нужно то hex-число, которое представляет содержимое сайта, перевести в десятичное. Споткнулся на двух вещах:

а) привычные мне алгоритмы записывают промежуточный вариант максимум в long long или их массив, и число для файла в пару кило(а то и мега-)байт ни в какую переменную, кроме текстовой, не влезет.
б) оптимизация, т.е. в первую очередь хотелось бы ускорения процесса. Если нагорожу первые мысли - процессор будет удивлен.

Собственно, хотелось бы почитать ваши мысли об алгоритме (в идеале C/ C++ / php). Выводить можно на ходу в stdout.

Пример перевода - 'яю'(0xFFFE) => '65534';

```
// свою попытку я убрал, глупость написал
```

Comment: А зачем всё это? Почему не использовать просто md5?

Comment: Нужен не хэш, а именно весь контент файла в DEC. Т.к. мое объясниние неадекватно и потребует еще на пару страниц предпосылки расписать, можно считать, что это спортивный интерес :)
Предполагаю, что будет что-то типа "if (part > 10) { cout<< (part % 10); part -= (part % 10); } ", но мне это кажется долговатым =/

Comment: Не имеете ли вы в виду, что хотите представить весь файл как одно большое число?

Comment: Именно!)

Comment: Вообще, у вас какая-то странная задача.. держу пари, что вы пытаетесь "использовать круглую пробку для квадратной дырки" (c).

Comment: Практическую ценность можно найти в шифровании (как пример, у меня другая цель). Добавьте 16-битный ключ и представьте алгоритм дешифровки полученного файла без ключа и знания собственно алгоритма. Перебор точно будет занятным.

Comment: Одно из главных правил криптографии: знаниче алгоритма не должно создавать риск нарушения безопасности. Во-вторых, обработка файла целиком - очень неэффективно, и это действительно один из факторов криптостойкости. С другой стороны, вы забываете об эффективности для каждодневного использования. И, наконец, третее: у вас не всегда имеется на руках весь файл целиком, а запросто может быть поток. Это означает, что вы сможете шифровать только небольшими блоками. Небольшой блок + небольшой ключ = низкая криптостойкость в случае, если алгоритм известен.

Comment: Задача странная согласен - непонятно, зачем Вам такое число - Вы не сможете с ним сделать никакой операции - у вас ресурсов не хватит.
Если дело в представлении файла - то вряд ли это вызвало бы сложность.

Comment: Я повторюсь, это было "для себя", просто хотелось понять алгоритм такого преобразования. Увлекся в т.ч. тернарной логикой, представил файловую систему/хранение на троичных носителях, вот задачка и выплыла. Десятичную взял как человеко-сразу-понятную. З.Ы. я говорил, что причина неадекватна) Вообще разве никому не интересно, как это сделать?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно гигантское число, то используйте [BCD](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). BCD - это классика для работы с большими числами. Кроме того, как раз десятичное представление получите почти нахаляву.

Кроме того, в Java есть BigInteger. Ему можно задать любой размер и работать с ним просто как с числом. Не знаю насчёт PHP, но для C точно должны быть библиотеки для работы с гигантскими числами. К сожалению, не припомню с ходу ни одной.

Comment: Ну, так просто текстовое представление займёт ещё больше памяти. Ну, вы можете просто вручную делать всякие операции деления.. делить прямо весь файл.. довольно нужное занятие.. Учитывая, что файл может быть большим, то вам придётся выполнять деление не в памяти, а на диске..

Comment: Имел в виду оперативную, да. Сам перевод, как мне что-то подсказывает, можно уместить в unsigned int + char. Попробую накидать примерно.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php

Comment: http://www.php.ru/manual/ref.gmp.html